# How to assert that a node value is associated with another node value

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have the following XML from querying a database

```
<Results>
   <ResultSet fetchSize="128">
      <Row rowNumber="1">
         <REGISTRATIONKEY>1644606</REGISTRATIONKEY>
         <WORKFLOWACTIVITY>Fraud Identity Validation (NegMatch)</WORKFLOWACTIVITY>
         <WORKFLOWACTIVITYKEY>3</WORKFLOWACTIVITYKEY>
         <WORKFLOWACTIVITYSTATUSKEY>2</WORKFLOWACTIVITYSTATUSKEY>
         <WORKFLOWACTIVITYSTATUS>Passed</WORKFLOWACTIVITYSTATUS>
         <WORKFLOWPROCESSKEY>1</WORKFLOWPROCESSKEY>
         <WORKFLOWPROCESSSTATUSKEY>1</WORKFLOWPROCESSSTATUSKEY>
         <WORKFLOWPROCESS>CardAccountRegistration</WORKFLOWPROCESS>
         <WORKFLOWPROCESSSTATUS>Started</WORKFLOWPROCESSSTATUS>
         <CREATEDATE>2016-12-29 15:29:25.3</CREATEDATE>
      </Row>
      <Row rowNumber="2">
         <REGISTRATIONKEY>1644606</REGISTRATIONKEY>
         <WORKFLOWACTIVITY>Age Verification</WORKFLOWACTIVITY>
         <WORKFLOWACTIVITYKEY>6</WORKFLOWACTIVITYKEY>
         <WORKFLOWACTIVITYSTATUSKEY>2</WORKFLOWACTIVITYSTATUSKEY>
         <WORKFLOWACTIVITYSTATUS>Passed</WORKFLOWACTIVITYSTATUS>
         <WORKFLOWPROCESSKEY>1</WORKFLOWPROCESSKEY>
         <WORKFLOWPROCESSSTATUSKEY>1</WORKFLOWPROCESSSTATUSKEY>
         <WORKFLOWPROCESS>CardAccountRegistration</WORKFLOWPROCESS>
         <WORKFLOWPROCESSSTATUS>Started</WORKFLOWPROCESSSTATUS>
         <CREATEDATE>2016-12-29 15:29:25.3</CREATEDATE>
      </Row>
      <Row rowNumber="3">
         <REGISTRATIONKEY>1644606</REGISTRATIONKEY>
         <WORKFLOWACTIVITY>Address Validation</WORKFLOWACTIVITY>
         <WORKFLOWACTIVITYKEY>2</WORKFLOWACTIVITYKEY>
         <WORKFLOWACTIVITYSTATUSKEY>2</WORKFLOWACTIVITYSTATUSKEY>
         <WORKFLOWACTIVITYSTATUS>Passed</WORKFLOWACTIVITYSTATUS>
         <WORKFLOWPROCESSKEY>1</WORKFLOWPROCESSKEY>
         <WORKFLOWPROCESSSTATUSKEY>1</WORKFLOWPROCESSSTATUSKEY>
         <WORKFLOWPROCESS>CardAccountRegistration</WORKFLOWPROCESS>
         <WORKFLOWPROCESSSTATUS>Started</WORKFLOWPROCESSSTATUS>
         <CREATEDATE>2016-12-29 15:29:25.3</CREATEDATE>
      </Row>
      <Row rowNumber="4">
         <REGISTRATIONKEY>1644606</REGISTRATIONKEY>
         <WORKFLOWACTIVITY>Card Limit Validation</WORKFLOWACTIVITY>
         <WORKFLOWACTIVITYKEY>4</WORKFLOWACTIVITYKEY>
         <WORKFLOWACTIVITYSTATUSKEY>2</WORKFLOWACTIVITYSTATUSKEY>
         <WORKFLOWACTIVITYSTATUS>Passed</WORKFLOWACTIVITYSTATUS>
         <WORKFLOWPROCESSKEY>1</WORKFLOWPROCESSKEY>
         <WORKFLOWPROCESSSTATUSKEY>1</WORKFLOWPROCESSSTATUSKEY>
         <WORKFLOWPROCESS>CardAccountRegistration</WORKFLOWPROCESS>
         <WORKFLOWPROCESSSTATUS>Started</WORKFLOWPROCESSSTATUS>
         <CREATEDATE>2016-12-29 15:29:25.3</CREATEDATE>
      </Row>
      <Row rowNumber="5">
         <REGISTRATIONKEY>1644606</REGISTRATIONKEY>
         <WORKFLOWACTIVITY>Customer Identity Validation (CIP)</WORKFLOWACTIVITY>
         <WORKFLOWACTIVITYKEY>5</WORKFLOWACTIVITYKEY>
         <WORKFLOWACTIVITYSTATUSKEY>3</WORKFLOWACTIVITYSTATUSKEY>
         <WORKFLOWACTIVITYSTATUS>Failed</WORKFLOWACTIVITYSTATUS>
         <WORKFLOWPROCESSKEY>1</WORKFLOWPROCESSKEY>
         <WORKFLOWPROCESSSTATUSKEY>1</WORKFLOWPROCESSSTATUSKEY>
         <WORKFLOWPROCESS>CardAccountRegistration</WORKFLOWPROCESS>
         <WORKFLOWPROCESSSTATUS>Started</WORKFLOWPROCESSSTATUS>
         <CREATEDATE>2016-12-29 15:29:25.503</CREATEDATE>
      </Row>
      <Row rowNumber="6">
         <REGISTRATIONKEY>1644606</REGISTRATIONKEY>
         <WORKFLOWACTIVITY>Out Of Wallet Quiz</WORKFLOWACTIVITY>
         <WORKFLOWACTIVITYKEY>11</WORKFLOWACTIVITYKEY>
         <WORKFLOWACTIVITYSTATUSKEY>4</WORKFLOWACTIVITYSTATUSKEY>
         <WORKFLOWACTIVITYSTATUS>Skipped</WORKFLOWACTIVITYSTATUS>
         <WORKFLOWPROCESSKEY>1</WORKFLOWPROCESSKEY>
         <WORKFLOWPROCESSSTATUSKEY>1</WORKFLOWPROCESSSTATUSKEY>
         <WORKFLOWPROCESS>CardAccountRegistration</WORKFLOWPROCESS>
         <WORKFLOWPROCESSSTATUS>Started</WORKFLOWPROCESSSTATUS>
         <CREATEDATE>2016-12-29 15:29:25.613</CREATEDATE>
      </Row>
      <Row rowNumber="7">
         <REGISTRATIONKEY>1644606</REGISTRATIONKEY>
         <WORKFLOWACTIVITY>OFAC</WORKFLOWACTIVITY>
         <WORKFLOWACTIVITYKEY>7</WORKFLOWACTIVITYKEY>
         <WORKFLOWACTIVITYSTATUSKEY>2</WORKFLOWACTIVITYSTATUSKEY>
         <WORKFLOWACTIVITYSTATUS>Passed</WORKFLOWACTIVITYSTATUS>
         <WORKFLOWPROCESSKEY>1</WORKFLOWPROCESSKEY>
         <WORKFLOWPROCESSSTATUSKEY>1</WORKFLOWPROCESSSTATUSKEY>
         <WORKFLOWPROCESS>CardAccountRegistration</WORKFLOWPROCESS>
         <WORKFLOWPROCESSSTATUS>Started</WORKFLOWPROCESSSTATUS>
         <CREATEDATE>2016-12-29 15:29:25.613</CREATEDATE>
      </Row>
   </ResultSet>
</Results>
```

How do I assert in groovy that one node value is associated or tied to another node value. So for example, I want to verify that the value "Customer Identity Validation (CIP)" from the WORKFLOWACTIVITY node, is tied to the value "Failed" from the WORKFLOWACTIVITYSTATUS node. And i'm not entirely sure if this chunk:

```
</Row>
<Row rowNumber="5">
<REGISTRATIONKEY>1644606</REGISTRATIONKEY>
<WORKFLOWACTIVITY>Customer Identity Validation (CIP)</WORKFLOWACTIVITY>
<WORKFLOWACTIVITYKEY>5</WORKFLOWACTIVITYKEY>
<WORKFLOWACTIVITYSTATUSKEY>3</WORKFLOWACTIVITYSTATUSKEY>
<WORKFLOWACTIVITYSTATUS>Failed</WORKFLOWACTIVITYSTATUS>
<WORKFLOWPROCESSKEY>1</WORKFLOWPROCESSKEY>
<WORKFLOWPROCESSSTATUSKEY>1</WORKFLOWPROCESSSTATUSKEY>
<WORKFLOWPROCESS>CardAccountRegistration</WORKFLOWPROCESS>
<WORKFLOWPROCESSSTATUS>Started</WORKFLOWPROCESSSTATUS>
<CREATEDATE>2016-12-29 15:29:25.503</CREATEDATE>
</Row>
```

will always come back as row 5

Comment: Is `Customer Identity Validation (CIP)`'s `WORKFLOWACTIVITYSTATUS` always be `Failed`? By the way, row number can be changed if more entries or entries are removed.

Comment: @Rao: For this particular scenario that i'm testing...yes, the WORKFLOWACTIVITYSTATUS for the WORKFLOWACTIVITY should always fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using `SoapUI` based on above the mentioned `jdbc` step result.
You can use the below `Script Assertion` for the same test step.

**Script Assertion**:

```
//Check if the result is not empty  
assert context.result

//Closure to get the sibling element data
def getSiblingData = { data, elementName, elementValue, siblingName ->
    def parsedResult = new XmlSlurper().parseText(data)
    (parsedResult.'**'.findAll {it.name() == elementName && it.text()== elementValue }*.parent()."$siblingName").inject( [] ) { result, item -> result << item.text(); result }
}

//Assert the result
//Note that data is passed to getSiblingData closure
assert ['Customer Identity Validation (CIP)'] == getSiblingData(context.response, 'WORKFLOWACTIVITYSTATUS', 'Failed', 'WORKFLOWACTIVITY')
```

If you want just `standalone groovy script`:

```
def results = """<Results>
   <ResultSet fetchSize="128">
      <Row rowNumber="1">
         <REGISTRATIONKEY>1644606</REGISTRATIONKEY>
         <WORKFLOWACTIVITY>Fraud Identity Validation (NegMatch)</WORKFLOWACTIVITY>
         <WORKFLOWACTIVITYKEY>3</WORKFLOWACTIVITYKEY>
         <WORKFLOWACTIVITYSTATUSKEY>2</WORKFLOWACTIVITYSTATUSKEY>
         <WORKFLOWACTIVITYSTATUS>Passed</WORKFLOWACTIVITYSTATUS>
         <WORKFLOWPROCESSKEY>1</WORKFLOWPROCESSKEY>
         <WORKFLOWPROCESSSTATUSKEY>1</WORKFLOWPROCESSSTATUSKEY>
         <WORKFLOWPROCESS>CardAccountRegistration</WORKFLOWPROCESS>
         <WORKFLOWPROCESSSTATUS>Started</WORKFLOWPROCESSSTATUS>
         <CREATEDATE>2016-12-29 15:29:25.3</CREATEDATE>
      </Row>
      <Row rowNumber="2">
         <REGISTRATIONKEY>1644606</REGISTRATIONKEY>
         <WORKFLOWACTIVITY>Age Verification</WORKFLOWACTIVITY>
         <WORKFLOWACTIVITYKEY>6</WORKFLOWACTIVITYKEY>
         <WORKFLOWACTIVITYSTATUSKEY>2</WORKFLOWACTIVITYSTATUSKEY>
         <WORKFLOWACTIVITYSTATUS>Passed</WORKFLOWACTIVITYSTATUS>
         <WORKFLOWPROCESSKEY>1</WORKFLOWPROCESSKEY>
         <WORKFLOWPROCESSSTATUSKEY>1</WORKFLOWPROCESSSTATUSKEY>
         <WORKFLOWPROCESS>CardAccountRegistration</WORKFLOWPROCESS>
         <WORKFLOWPROCESSSTATUS>Started</WORKFLOWPROCESSSTATUS>
         <CREATEDATE>2016-12-29 15:29:25.3</CREATEDATE>
      </Row>
      <Row rowNumber="3">
         <REGISTRATIONKEY>1644606</REGISTRATIONKEY>
         <WORKFLOWACTIVITY>Address Validation</WORKFLOWACTIVITY>
         <WORKFLOWACTIVITYKEY>2</WORKFLOWACTIVITYKEY>
         <WORKFLOWACTIVITYSTATUSKEY>2</WORKFLOWACTIVITYSTATUSKEY>
         <WORKFLOWACTIVITYSTATUS>Passed</WORKFLOWACTIVITYSTATUS>
         <WORKFLOWPROCESSKEY>1</WORKFLOWPROCESSKEY>
         <WORKFLOWPROCESSSTATUSKEY>1</WORKFLOWPROCESSSTATUSKEY>
         <WORKFLOWPROCESS>CardAccountRegistration</WORKFLOWPROCESS>
         <WORKFLOWPROCESSSTATUS>Started</WORKFLOWPROCESSSTATUS>
         <CREATEDATE>2016-12-29 15:29:25.3</CREATEDATE>
      </Row>
      <Row rowNumber="4">
         <REGISTRATIONKEY>1644606</REGISTRATIONKEY>
         <WORKFLOWACTIVITY>Card Limit Validation</WORKFLOWACTIVITY>
         <WORKFLOWACTIVITYKEY>4</WORKFLOWACTIVITYKEY>
         <WORKFLOWACTIVITYSTATUSKEY>2</WORKFLOWACTIVITYSTATUSKEY>
         <WORKFLOWACTIVITYSTATUS>Passed</WORKFLOWACTIVITYSTATUS>
         <WORKFLOWPROCESSKEY>1</WORKFLOWPROCESSKEY>
         <WORKFLOWPROCESSSTATUSKEY>1</WORKFLOWPROCESSSTATUSKEY>
         <WORKFLOWPROCESS>CardAccountRegistration</WORKFLOWPROCESS>
         <WORKFLOWPROCESSSTATUS>Started</WORKFLOWPROCESSSTATUS>
         <CREATEDATE>2016-12-29 15:29:25.3</CREATEDATE>
      </Row>
      <Row rowNumber="5">
         <REGISTRATIONKEY>1644606</REGISTRATIONKEY>
         <WORKFLOWACTIVITY>Customer Identity Validation (CIP)</WORKFLOWACTIVITY>
         <WORKFLOWACTIVITYKEY>5</WORKFLOWACTIVITYKEY>
         <WORKFLOWACTIVITYSTATUSKEY>3</WORKFLOWACTIVITYSTATUSKEY>
         <WORKFLOWACTIVITYSTATUS>Failed</WORKFLOWACTIVITYSTATUS>
         <WORKFLOWPROCESSKEY>1</WORKFLOWPROCESSKEY>
         <WORKFLOWPROCESSSTATUSKEY>1</WORKFLOWPROCESSSTATUSKEY>
         <WORKFLOWPROCESS>CardAccountRegistration</WORKFLOWPROCESS>
         <WORKFLOWPROCESSSTATUS>Started</WORKFLOWPROCESSSTATUS>
         <CREATEDATE>2016-12-29 15:29:25.503</CREATEDATE>
      </Row>
      <Row rowNumber="6">
         <REGISTRATIONKEY>1644606</REGISTRATIONKEY>
         <WORKFLOWACTIVITY>Out Of Wallet Quiz</WORKFLOWACTIVITY>
         <WORKFLOWACTIVITYKEY>11</WORKFLOWACTIVITYKEY>
         <WORKFLOWACTIVITYSTATUSKEY>4</WORKFLOWACTIVITYSTATUSKEY>
         <WORKFLOWACTIVITYSTATUS>Skipped</WORKFLOWACTIVITYSTATUS>
         <WORKFLOWPROCESSKEY>1</WORKFLOWPROCESSKEY>
         <WORKFLOWPROCESSSTATUSKEY>1</WORKFLOWPROCESSSTATUSKEY>
         <WORKFLOWPROCESS>CardAccountRegistration</WORKFLOWPROCESS>
         <WORKFLOWPROCESSSTATUS>Started</WORKFLOWPROCESSSTATUS>
         <CREATEDATE>2016-12-29 15:29:25.613</CREATEDATE>
      </Row>
      <Row rowNumber="7">
         <REGISTRATIONKEY>1644606</REGISTRATIONKEY>
         <WORKFLOWACTIVITY>OFAC</WORKFLOWACTIVITY>
         <WORKFLOWACTIVITYKEY>7</WORKFLOWACTIVITYKEY>
         <WORKFLOWACTIVITYSTATUSKEY>2</WORKFLOWACTIVITYSTATUSKEY>
         <WORKFLOWACTIVITYSTATUS>Passed</WORKFLOWACTIVITYSTATUS>
         <WORKFLOWPROCESSKEY>1</WORKFLOWPROCESSKEY>
         <WORKFLOWPROCESSSTATUSKEY>1</WORKFLOWPROCESSSTATUSKEY>
         <WORKFLOWPROCESS>CardAccountRegistration</WORKFLOWPROCESS>
         <WORKFLOWPROCESSSTATUS>Started</WORKFLOWPROCESSSTATUS>
         <CREATEDATE>2016-12-29 15:29:25.613</CREATEDATE>
      </Row>
   </ResultSet>
</Results>"""

def getSiblingData = { data, elementName, elementValue, siblingName ->
    def parsedResult = new XmlSlurper().parseText(data)
    (parsedResult.'**'.findAll {it.name() == elementName && it.text()== elementValue }*.parent()."$siblingName").inject( [] ) { result, item -> result << item.text(); result }
}

assert ['Customer Identity Validation (CIP)'] == getSiblingData(results, 'WORKFLOWACTIVITYSTATUS', 'Failed', 'WORKFLOWACTIVITY')
```